# How to "heapify" array based min heap after remove min?

Tags: java, arrays, heap, min-heap

How would I "heapify" an array based minimum heap in java once the remove min function has been called (this simply takes the element at index 1 and removes it, and then replaces it with the last item in the array). I'm confused as to how I would go about putting the array into a minimum heap again after the remove min has happened.

The index 0 is always kept empty in the heap minimum array. The parent index is i/2, the right child is 2i + 1, and the left child is 2i.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the last element and copy it to the first position. Reduce heapsize by one and call `heapify()` on the first element. The heap should repair itself. This has complexity of O(log n)

```
Min-Heapify-Down (Array A, int i):
    left ← 2i
    right ← 2i + 1
    smallest ← i

    if left ≤ heap_length[A] and A[left] < A[smallest] then:
        smallest ← left
    if right ≤ heap_length[A] and A[right] < A[smallest] then:
        smallest ← right

    if smallest ≠ i then:
        swap A[i] ↔ A[smallest]
        Min-Heapify-Down(A, smallest)
```

Comment: What would the heapify code look like for that though?

Comment: It's the same heapify() you use when building the heap.

Comment: The thing is, the heapify that I used in building the heap uses the parent as the comparator, so what would I compare the new index 1 element to since it has no parent. That's what is confusing me.

Comment: @Vimzy It sounds like you need to look at the difference between the "heapify-up" and "heapify-down" procedures. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap

Comment: As @Sneftel mentioned, you need to use heapify-down. The code on wikipedia article is for max heap. You just need to modify it to work on min heap.

Comment: Can we write the modified one here? It'd probably help future readers as well!

Comment: I took the code from wikipedia and modified it for min heap. It's been a long time since I implemented binary heap, so I'm hoping I haven't made any errors

Comment: What do we set the last element to after setting it to index 1? Do we set it to 0?

Comment: 2 options. Either set it to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (or MAX_VALUE from the data type you are using). This works for primitive types or for objects that have some sort of MAX_VALUE. However if a legitimate MAX_VALUE is inserted into the heap it might cause problems. The other option is keeping a `heapSize` variable and just decrement it by one. The `heapify()` (and other methods) should check the `heapSize` and make sure they are not out of bounds. The second option is much better, but bit more complex.